# Does the Compiz Cube plugin work with Unity?

Tags: unity, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to correctly enable Desktop Cube in Unity 3D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86977/how-to-correctly-enable-desktop-cube-in-unity-3d)

I can't currently enable Compiz Cube. It conflicts with the Desktop Wall plugin, and that plugin is required for Unity. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 13):

This is currently [by design](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/711561) as the plugin requires the wall as part of the switching experience.

The cube is not officially supported but you can work around it if you're willing to keep both pieces if it breaks:

- [How do I enable the 3D Cube so I can use it in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-enable-the-3d-cube-so-i-can-use-it-in-unity)

Answer (score 3):

Right now you can use it. I'm using it for a week right now with no problems. There's a bug in ccsm that causes to lose all the settings, but you can reenable them easily. I've changed the number of virtual desktops to 4 hor - 1 vert. and have the cube with everything (reflections, etc..)

Working superb.

Here's my profile under "unity" in ccsm if you want to load it and try.

http://ubuntuone.com/p/sOi/