# How do I enable the 3D Cube so I can use it in Unity?

Tags: unity, 11.04, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to correctly enable Desktop Cube in Unity 3D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86977/how-to-correctly-enable-desktop-cube-in-unity-3d)

I'm looking to get the "3D Cube" in Ubuntu 11.04 Beta 1, however last time I tried it after using compiz I lost my desktop and hand to reinstall. However I have read [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/711561) which seems to state this is fixed, however when I go to disable the wall to enable the cube it still seems like its going to break it ( I dont want to try it again as it may break my desktop again :-)  )

Anyone able to shed any light on how I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

There are currently two issues:

1. Every time you enable or disable a plugin in *CompizConfig Settings Manager* (`ccsm`), Compiz (and therefore Unity) will crash.
2. *CompizConfig Settings Manager* fails to replace the *Wall* plugin with the *Desktop Cube* plugin.

One **really ugly** workaround is to manually set the plugins via the commandline:

```
gconftool-2 --type l --list-type string --set /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/active_plugins "[core,bailer,detection,composite,opengl,compiztoolbox,decor,move,vpswitch,place,mousepoll,resize,staticswitcher,imgpng,regex,gnomecompat,grid,snap,zoom,session,animation,workarounds,fade,cube,expo,scale,rotate,unityshell,unitymtgrabhandles]" && (unity &)
```

Running this will set the plugins to Unity's default, but will replace *Wall* with *Desktop Cube* and *Rotate Cube*.

Unity's default is to have 2x2 desktops, but for the cube you'll likely want 4x1 desktops. You can change this in the *General Options* plugin in the *CompizConfig Settings Manager*. Go to the *Desktop Size* tab, and change *Horizontal Virtual Size* to 4 and *Vertical Virtual Size* to 1.

[image]

You should now be able to rotate the cube using the default shortcuts:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>  and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

that bug is fixed in unity 3.8.4.
The Beta uses an earlier version of unity. <s>so install the updates and test again.</s>
I tested it with my system. it doesn't yet work using compiz settings

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I've just tested it but run into the same problem, is there any way to get my normal taskbars etc back? I can't even use alt-f2 to run anything

thanks again

Comment: @user12622 this should get your working setup back: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration

Answer (score 0):

For 12.04 64 bit the following instructions worked well for me:  http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.com/2011/06/enable-3d-cube-with-unity-in-ubuntu.html