# How to get compiz cube effect to work in classic mode?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, compiz

I installed CCSM (Configure Compiz with CompizConfig) and configure to use effects, desktop cube and rotate cube. But It does not work on my laptop, MSI CR420.

I don't use compiz on Unity (NN 11.04). I configure compiz on Ubuntu Classic(NN 11.04) session and want to use it on that session only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable the 3D Cube so I can use it in Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34588/how-do-i-enable-the-3d-cube-so-i-can-use-it-in-unity)

Answer (score 3):

I didnt like UNITY as well; so i run Ubuntu Classic, also NN 11.04...
I already installed CCSM (CompizConfig Settings Manager); and desktop cube only shows 2 of the 4 workspaces i use... I would have to use "super + s" (thats "WindowsKey + S"), to open EXPO and click on the 2 lower desktops.

SOLUTION: edit workspaces; from 2 columns & 2 rows... simply 4 columns.
How to edit workspaces? Right click on the "Current Workspace" icon(s) on any of the taskbars and go for Preferences.

Easy once youve figured it out...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide enough details. If u use Unity (NN 11.04) desktop cube effect collides with unity plugin that is required to run unity desktop. So unfortunately desktop wall is the optimal effect for switching between workspaces.

Comment: Yes. I noticed compiz may not work on Unity. I don't use compiz on Unity (NN 11.04). I configure compiz on Ubuntu Classic(NN 11.04) session and want to use it on that session only.

Comment: Actually some of the stuff that i used in 10.10 still works with the Unity plugin and some are there by default (transparency, opacity and brightness options, expose like effects (super+w) wobbly windows, desktop wall, opening minimizing and closing window animations are compiz). You can also try ubuntu tweak (recently updated) for some common compiz options that work well with Unity so you dont have to navigate through all those options in the compiz configuration manager.

Comment: technically correct but here is a how to: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/compiz-cube-natty/ Yes it is not the easiest method (due to errors and editing textfiles) but in the end it seems to work ;)