# What does "compiz --replace" do?

Tags: compiz

Sorry for the stupid question but I am new with Linux (I am using Gnome classic with Ubuntu 12.04) and I cannot set compiz in order to obtain the rotating cube.

I have already installed compizconfig-setting-manager and also the extra (and fusion) plugins but:

- even if I disable the desktop wall and enable cube and rotating cube, nothing happens;
- even if I change into general settings the number of vertical and horizontal virtual size  nothing happens.

What I need is (possibly) a step by step answer.

Thank you

---

Ok...I solved my problem by using the command.

```
compiz --replace
```

which I have found looking around.

Can someone explain me what I have precisely performed with this command?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What guidelines or instructions you followed? Edit the question to include that.

Comment: [link](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Cube) and other italian pages. I think also that one issue could be the fact that until few days ago I used unity and my Gnome classic "derive" from the fact that I am using Gnome Shell...could it be?

Comment: You can check [this link](http://linux.about.com/od/dist_ubuntu/a/ubucompiz.htm) for  a good introduction. also do a compiz profile reset with `compizconfig-settings-manager`

Comment: I've done what you have suggested and after the reset I have changed to 4 the horizontal virtual size and I have crossed Desktop Cube and Rotate Cube. Anyway, it doesn't work yet.

Comment: check this question http://askubuntu.com/q/34588/61218. then update the question if you have any other query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `compiz --replace`, you have replaced any existing window manager with Compiz; if you were already using Compiz, you have "reset" (or re-initialized) it -- which probably explains why this command solved your problem by finally applying your custom settings.

Comment: A new problem had emerged. Now I cannot move any window from one desktop to another; moreover I cannot resize the windows. Can you tell me what to do?

Comment: @Keynesian: first, try rebooting. Otherwise, could you please start a new question, describing the steps you took to change Compiz from its default configuration? After that the solution should be easy (because I or others can attempt to replicate your problem if necessary).